# GSL: Random number generator should be unique in one program

Tags: gnu, gsl

I am using GNU Scientific Library to generate random number. [Random Number Generation — GSL 2.7 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/rng.html)

In general, we should get a `gsl_rng` firstly.

```c
       const gsl_rng_type * T;
       gsl_rng * r;
     
       int i, n = 10;
     
       gsl_rng_env_setup();
     
       T = gsl_rng_default;
       r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
```

But should we use **one** `gsl_rng` in **one** program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/rng.html, the first paragraph)

> Each instance of a generator keeps track of its own state, allowing the generators to be used in multi-threaded programs.

This implies that you can have as many instances of `gsl_rng` as you wish.